# Does washroom silicone caulk turn into goo after time?

Tags: bathroom, caulking, silicone

I found this tube of clear washroom GE caulk in the closet that hasn't been used in over a year.  When I tried to apply it yesterday, it was like goo even after drying it for 24 hours.  I want to know if caulk is supposed to be gooey after being unused for a long time or I simply need to wait longer for it to dry (even though the instruction I need to wait 3 hours before exposing the caulk to water).  I am used GE Premium Waterproof Silicone Clear - 3 Hr Shower ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/why-would-silicone-caulk-not-cure

Comment: What is the expiration date on the caulk cartridge?  (it's hard to see if it's mounted in a gun; just rotate it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Silicone caulk has a surprisingly [short expiry date](https://www.hunker.com/13415538/does-silicone-caulk-go-bad).  My nonprofit has loads of the stuff all over the shop; people love to donate it when it's expired. Into the trash it goes.

It is degraded and will not work. It won't take longer to cure; *it won't work at all*.

If the stuff is not behaving as you expect, **don't chance it**.  Bad caulk is like bad paint: **It will ruin your project and [make you spend hours](https://thepatriotwoodworker.com/forums/topic/19476-expired-silicone-sealant/) cleaning it off for good product to stick**.

The caulk tube certainly has an expiration date stated on it. If it's not obvious, try rotating the tube in the caulk gun.  **This date is valid if it's stored at room temperature** - if it's stored in a hot attic or cold garage, *all bets are off*.

If it's so old that no expiry date is stated, then it's *way* too old.

Answer (score 0):

Wait another few days before you start being concerned.

When caulk goes bad it doesn't even come out of the tube.

3 hours before exposing the caulk to water, and probably at least 48 hours for full cure. Even after that, if it's good caulk, it will still feel a little gooey. Quit poking at it. You're done here.

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully 48 hours will do it.